# Need to run BCP utility through .net code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How can I run the Bulk Copy Program (BCP) utility of SQL Server through .Net code?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.  And there's [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a.aspx) with examples.

Comment: This will only let you INSERT data, not export it.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute this SQL command in a Command object

```
BULK INSERT <TableName> from '<FileName>' with (FORMATFILE='<FmtFile>')
```

Replacing the items in angle brackets with proper item names

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible options:

1. From .NET 2.0, we can use SqlBulkCopy class
2. Use BULK INSERT Query
3. Use an integration service package (SISS).

...and

4. If you still need bcp utility, then you can run it as a process... which I will reccomend less.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late, but may be helpful for someone else.

I had tested this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExportLargeData
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C bcp databasname..tablename out D:\\NewFolder\\filename.csv -S .\\ -c -C RAW -T";
```

Important is that the argument begins with /C otherwise it won't work. And after -S you have to pass SQL Server Instance in my case its local so I pass .\

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to execute stored procedure then the command will be

```
string proc = "Exec database..storedprocedurename";
string strCmdText = "/C bcp "+ proc + " queryout D:\\NewFolder\\filename.csv -T -c -S .\\";
```